# How to formart numeric field to decimal places or leave a full a full stop in the datagrid cell

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I have a datagrid in VB6 that I am populating with an ADODC recordset object. I have successfully managed to format the numeric field to 2 decimal places but now what i want is that if the value in the field is zero the it must truncate all the trailing zeros and leave only a full stop in the cell. How can I go about this?

In other words if the value in the cell is 2 I want it to show 2.00

If its 0 I want it to show . ( The full stop)

Please Note I am using the Property Pages dialog Box of the Datagrid control in VB6. The **Format** Tab in the Custom **Format Type** Category. In the Format String Textbox

Answer (score 1):

Start the IDE and start a new standard EXE Project.

Add ths code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    AutoRedraw = True
    Font.Size = 12
    Print Format$(871.35, "0.00;-0.00;.")
    Print Format$(0, "0.00;-0.00;.")
    Print Format$(-12.6, "0.00;-0.00;.")
End Sub
```

I think you'll find this format string does what you are asking for.  If not, you can tweak it as needed.

The same kind of string should be usable in your grid control.